# How to undo actions performed by a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I am currently working on a basic implementation of a scrabble-like game of forming words from random letters on Swing, and I need help with one aspect of it. To explain the view in short, I have created a 6X6 grid of JButtons (which I have implemented as tiles) at the center panel, with two Jbuttons (Submit and Done) at the top panel. My code for the ActionPerformed method is given below. Please note that I have a separate class called Tile that gives the graphical representation of a JButton and has the same methods as  the JButton.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String choice = e.getActionCommand();

    if(!choice.equals("Done") && !choice.equals("Submit"))
    {
        for(int j=0; j<6; j++)
        {
            for(int k=0; k<6; k++)
            {

            if(tile[j][k]==e.getSource())
            { 
                current+=(tile[j][k].getTile().letter());  //gets each letter of the clicked Tiles and adds it to a String variable 'current'
                score+=(tile[j][k].getTile().value());    //gets the value of the tiles to calculate the score

                tile[j][k].setForeground(Color.blue);
                tile[j][k].removeActionListener(this);
                tile[j][k].setEnabled(false); //the tile can only be clicked once

                //rest of the code to set rules for adjacent tiles etc
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the user selects a wrong word and clicks on the Submit button, I want to undo all the selected tiles, which should get back to normal. Or, I can add an Undo button that the user can select manually. I was at first thinking of implementing a method to shuffle the tiles, but this was difficult for me and I decided to rather undo the clicked buttons.

Could someone please help me with this? I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep track of the tiles that have been selected using a `Stack`.

```
Stack<Tile> history = new Stack<Tile>();
```

in your actionPerformed method:

```
if(tile[j][k]==e.getSource())
 {
     ...
     history.push(tile[j][k]);
     ...
 }

 if(choice.equals("Undo"))
 {
     Tile previous = history.pop(); //be sure to handle EmptyStackException 
     //TODO undo the actions of the Tile: subtract score, remote letter, enable the button
 }
```

also, I suggest you change this line of code:

```
if(!choice.equals("Done") && !choice.equals("Submit"))
```

This is executing the if-then block of code for every action command that does not equal "Done" or "Submit". Now that you will have an Undo command, it will execute it, which is not what you want.

Edit:

A more complete code example, as requested:

```
Stack<Tile> history = new Stack<Tile>();

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String choice = e.getActionCommand();

    if(choice.equals("Click"))
    {
        for(int j=0; j<6; j++)
        {
            for(int k=0; k<6; k++)
            {
                if(tile[j][k]==e.getSource())
                { 
                    current+=(tile[j][k].getTile().letter());  //gets each letter of the clicked Tiles and adds it to a String variable 'current'
                    score+=(tile[j][k].getTile().value());    //gets the value of the tiles to calculate the score

                    tile[j][k].setForeground(Color.blue);
                    tile[j][k].removeActionListener(this);
                    tile[j][k].setEnabled(false); //the tile can only be clicked once

                    history.push(tile[j][k]);

                    // rest of the code to set rules for adjacent tiles etc
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    else if(choice.equals("Undo"))
    {
        Tile previous = history.pop(); //be sure to handle EmptyStackException 
        //TODO undo the actions of the Tile: subtract score, remote letter, enable the button
    }
    else if(choice.equals("Submit"))
    {
        //...
    }
    else if(choice.equals("Done"))
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. Since my for-loop for the buttons clicked is outside this if statement, I do not understand how I will enable each button clicked. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: As in, the for loop: `for(int j=0; j<6; j++)
        {
            for(int k=0; k<6; k++)
            { 
            if(tile[j][k]==e.getSource())
            { `
how can I use it to enable the tile when it is outside the If statement that you gave

Comment: Give me a minute and I will include a more complete code sample from what you gave me

Comment: Please see my edit. Notice that I added a new Action command "Click". You will need to specify that action for the Tile clicks.

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering you, but I do not understand what you have done. How does this help me implement the undo button?

Comment: It's no problem I'm happy to help. Your question is "how to undo actions performed by a JButton" not "how to implement a JButton". I can't really help you with that because you don't provide enough code. The code I provided should be enough, all you need to do is add a JButton to your GUi, and then add your actionlistener to it, with the action command "Undo".

Comment: You are right in that case. No problem, I figured it out :)